# extjs store.load after form.submit

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to reload an Extjs-store, after user has download a PDF.

The process is the following:

- User double clicks a cell in GridPanel
- Form is created, submitted, and a procedure in the  backend creates an PDF and makes some changes on data of GridPanel store
- PDF will be downloaded by user

But how to reload the store with the new data in it?
There is no afterRender on form-submit.

I think this should be an easy problem, but I do not have any ideas how to solve it.

Comment: Hello @Larky. It is always a good idea to post some code in your question for the better understanding of the answerers. And if you need the fastest response then also try to include a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com). Thanks

Comment: yes, you are totally right, but I have problems with downloadWindow in my Fiddle, so I tried without. Here is my link: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2m4u

Answer (score 0):

This is a snipped I found in my code base (inside a controller):

```
var form = button.up().up().down('form').getForm();
form.submit({ success : this.onFileUpload, failure: this.onFileUpload, scope: this});
...
onFileUpload: function (form, action){
    var data = action.result.data;
    ...
    if (action.result.success){
    ...
       //**your store reload could be here!**
    ...
    } else {
      ...
    }
}
```

My form response is not responding with a file (just some standard html return), but I guess it should work.

Comment: I tried this one..
But it does not work for me, because reloading of the store does not work if I put it in success of submit. If i restart it after that in my firebug, everything works fine, so I think the Request is fine, but perhaps it tries to reload in scope of new Form?

Answer (score 0):

here is a bit of my code:

```js
function makeprintForm(array, setStatusX, grid) {

     var filename = 'asd.pdf';

     var url_pdf = 'someURL?FileName=' + filename;

     var printForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', ({

          url: currentContextPath + encodeURIComponent('http://' + host + ':' + port + url_pdf),
          hidden: true,
          id: 'printForm',
          name: 'printForm',
          method: 'post',
          standardSubmit: true,
          target: '_blank',
          items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'print_id',
                    name: 'print_id',
                    value: array
               },
               {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'username',
                    name: 'username',
                    value: username
               },
               {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'language_field',
                    name: 'language',
                    value: language
               }
          ]
     }));

     Ext.getCmp('printForm').getForm().submit({ success : this.reload_grid_after_submit(), scope: document.getElementById(nameSpace + 'formIS')});
}

function reload_grid_after_submit(){
     console.log('reload_grid_after_submit');
     Ext.getCmp('grid').getStore().proxy.setExtraParam('status', 'NEW');
     Ext.getCmp('grid').getStore().load();
}
```

Comment: You can always edit your question and add the code there. Just to avoid confusing answer seekers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a form in an alert box. I used a window here. Then onsubmit of the form you can use findRecord to find a record from the store and edit it. For better explanation please find the fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2mja). P.S sorry for the delay I was on a vacation. Please mark it as an answer if it's correct so it helps other people in the future. Or please comment if there is something which needs to be changed. Thanks

```
Ext.getCmp('myGrid').addListener('rowdblclick', function (a, b, c, d) {

    win = new Ext.Window({
        width: 300,
        height: 150,
        draggable: false,
        border: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'What is your new name',
            id: 'newNameField'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            name: 'sampleButton',
            text: 'Change My Name!',
            style: 'margin:15px',
            width: 150,
            handler: function () {
                name = Ext.getCmp('myGrid').getStore().getAt(d).data['name'];
                console.log(name);
                var newName = Ext.getCmp("newNameField").value;
                console.log("replacing " + name + " with " + newName + " in the store");
                var entry = userStore.findRecord('name', name);
                entry.set('name', newName);
                win.hide();

            }
        }]
    })
    win.show();

})
```